# Can I call a function which depends on the decison variables in an objective function when using docplex?

Tags: docplex, callback

I have a math model as shown below, which I want to solve with cplex via docplex. In my model, the decision variables represent an assignment to different places. In my objective function, I call a function that calculates the distance between two places as a function of all other variables. Can I call the function in the target function without any problems and pass it all variables as arguments, as in the example?

```
N = 6
X = 6
Y = 6
O = 4
flow = 2
M =3000

def tc(P, n, m):
  #calculations  
  return something

mod = Model("mod")
P = mod.var_hypercube(vartype_spec='B', seq_of_keys=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3]])

gw_fkt = sum(sum(sum(sum(P[n, x_n, y_n, o_n]* tc(P, n,m) for n in range(N)) for x_n in range(X)) for o_n in range(O)) for y_n in range(Y))
#restrictions
for n in range(N):
    mod.add_constraint(sum(sum(sum(P[n, x, y, o] for x in range(X)) for y in range(Y)) for o in range(O)) == 1)
```

Comment: A: **If you are assuming delayed / lazy invocation based on passing currently-optimized variable-instantiations as arguments: no... this is impossible**. B: **If you are talking about immediate / eager invocation which returns a *constant* passed to cplex' model-builder: yes**. While there is much to say about A, among other issues: solver needs a linear-model, e.g. affine-functions and as transforming just ANY function to this is not possible, more structure / restrictions are needed which are missing here (e.g. compile-time type-based checking based on some function-composition framework).

Comment: There might be black-box / global-optimization solvers supporting A (or doing this through third-party libs) by making use of automatic-differentiation (as in machine-learning frameworks). But also then, there are limits about what exactly is allowed to happen in your function (e.g. twice differentiable). Meaning: another view on assumptions! | Thought experiment: think about what will happen in A when `tc(P, n, m)` is non-deterministic (e.g. `return random()`). There are surely solvers supporting this kind of stochasticity, but i think it hints potential issues.